# Where can I learn about the "symbols"that are used in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Besides regular expressions and selectors, where can I learn what the symbols mean.. such as

```
[0]=-
```

and characters like that. Ive read 2 books about jQuery and this still gives me a hard  time to understand. Is there a cheat sheet, or an eBook or tutorial on these?

Sorry its so cold here in Virginia its hard to type.

example:

```
$("img[alt='moon']").animate({left:'+=256'},2500,function(){
```

I know what .animate does, just not those symbols. Theres alot more then that.

Edit: Okay I found out they are called "Operators". Any guide, book, tutorial that can explains these?

Comment: Please provide a context in which `[0]=-` is used.  That alone means nothing.

Comment: left:+=256  means add 256 to the current left value, and it's not jQuery stuff is almost universal in most languages.  in C left+=256; is the same as left = left + 256;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this W3C page will explain it better than I:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: THIS.. this is what I mean. Besides W3C any site or guide these?

Comment: These are pretty standard to all C-style languages, so you're going to have to do better than "I don't understand any C-style languages" ... if you're going to tell us that you might as well go visit a library or a bookstore, the resources there will help you to learn better than a list of websites. However, most of us cut our teeth on C-style languages so I'm surprised to meet anyone who doesn't know them.

Comment: No offense, but this should not need a tutorial. Looking at the table under the *JavaScript Assignment Operators* heading should be sufficient, as it gives you an example as well as what they are equivalent to.

Comment: @Felix, I agree that I don't find it good for most things, but in this case, its all he needs in my opinion.  Never been on that Mozilla site though. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Note that W3Schools is *not* a W3C site and it's generally regarded as unreliable by the majority of experienced web developers

Comment: @simshaun: The Mozilla site is really good imo, you just have to be careful about Firefox-only features...

Answer (score 3):

All "special" symbols used by jQuery are for sure described in the [*documentation*](http://api.jquery.com/). E.g. for [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

And for the selector syntax: [*jQuery Selectors*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

So if you find a method that uses "special" symbols, check its documentation. If you can't find any information there, it is probably normal JavaScript syntax and you should consult a [*JavaScript reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference).